# How can i re-use a function across multiple directive hooks?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I have a directive that updates how an elements looks when its content changes. As such, I need it to run both when its native `change` event fires, and when the element is first set up. So I run my function in the `bind` hook, and in the `componentUpdated` hook.

So the structure of that looks something like this:

```js
directives: {
    demo: {
        bind(el) {
            el.addEventListener('change', () => {
                alert('i am a directive function');
            });
        },

        componentUpdated(el) {
            alert('i am a directive function');
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but i had to copy and paste the function in both hook declarations, and i would like to get rid of that.

I thought maybe a directive declaration could have its local properties, accessible through `this`, so i tried to solve it like so:

```js
directives: {
    demo: {
        myFunction: () => {
            alert('i am a directive function');
        },

        bind(el) {
            el.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.myFunction());
        },

        componentUpdated(el) {
            this.myFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

But that didn't work, saying `this.myFunction` is not a function.

How would I make this work?

Comment: I would just move `myFunction` outside the directive into a standalone function that could be called anywhere. e.g., `function myFunction() { ... }` and then just use `myFunction()` where needed.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very separation-of-concerns-like thing to do. Ideally i would want directives to be sort of plug & play and easily reusable.

Comment: Hmm, I must be missing something. Why would an external function preclude plug&play or reusability? My answer below (option 2) demonstrates what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: Separate directive variable

Define the directive in its own variable that could be referenced by name instead of `this`:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
const myDirective = {
  myFunction(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  },
  bind(el, { value }) {
    el.addEventListener('keyup', () => myDirective.myFunction(value))
  },
  componentUpdated(el, { value }) {
    myDirective.myFunction(value)
  }
}

export default {
  directives: {
    myDirective
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/directives-in-vue-d3jo7?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fmy-directive.js&theme=dark)

#### Option 2: Separate function

Define the common function externally from the directive, and use where needed:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
function myFunction(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}

export default {
  directives: {
    myDirective: {
      bind(el, { value }) {
        el.addEventListener('keyup', () => myFunction(value))
      },
      componentUpdated(el, { value }) {
        myFunction(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/directives-in-vue-forked-zsp8j?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fmy-directive.js&theme=dark)

*In both examples above, the directives could be moved to their own file, which would increase their testability and improve the readability of the component.*

Comment: Yea, the option 2 is the one i meant i didn't want because it was declaring a global function (i'm in a non-cli app atm). Option 1 is exactly what i wished for and tried, but i didn't know how to correctly access the function (i tried with `this`). So that works. Thx!